# Using UITextAlignmentCenter with @selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to change the alignment of a UILabel on the main thread like this

```
[updateLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setTextAlignment:) withObject:UITextAlignmentCenter waitUntilDone:YES];
```

However this generates a "makes pointer from integer without cast error.  What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: `updateLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;`

why not?

Comment: I need to call the selector on the main thread rather than the current thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to work because `UITextAlignmentCenter` is not a pointer to an object, but a simple integer. A solution is to implement an own method on the view controller that sets the alignment to center via `updateLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;` and calling `[yourViewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setUpdateLabelTextAlignmentToCenter) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];`

Comment: Thanks, adding my own method to do it worked.  Thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a raw integer to "withObject" instead of an object, that's why you're getting the error.  Instead, you could call a selector of your own on the main thread that does the job for you, passing in a dictionary or array containing the UILable object to change, and the new alignment value packaged up as a NSNumber:

```
- (void) changeLabelAlignment:(NSArray *)argsArray
{
    UILabel *lbl = [argsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    int alignment = [[argsArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
    lbl.textAlignment = alignment;
}
```

calling it this way:

```
...
NSArray *argsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:label, [NSNumber numberWithInt: UITextAlignmentCenter], nil];
[myClassObject  performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeLabelAlignment:) 
                                    withObject:argsArray
                                 waitUntilDone:YES];
```